# RecyclerView clicks twice after adding new items

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a RecyclerView display some data depending on what the user searches for.When the user clicks on one of the items it launches a new intent with more information regarding the item that he clicked.In the first search it works fine but when i clear the recyclerview and add new items then the five first items launch the intent twice while the rest of the 5 launch it once(what is supposed to happen)

MatchListCustomAdapter.cs

```
  private void MMainView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int position = mRecyclerView.GetChildLayoutPosition((View)sender);


            mainAct.launchActivity(mgame[position].Id);
        }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
 private void function1()
        {
            //Clears the list at the beginning and each time a new user is queried so it doesn't add more than 10 games.
            game.Clear();
            mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is from the recentgamesdoworkcompleted");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //This sets the color of the listview depending if it's a victory or defeat.
                if (mclass.win[i])
                {
                    winorlose = Color.ParseColor("#42A5F5");
                }
                else
                {
                    winorlose = Color.ParseColor("#D32F2F");

                }
                game.Add(new Models.MatchHistoryListView()
                {
                    Name = "" + mclass.summonerId[0, i],
                    ChampionId = mclass.championId[0, i],
                    Id = mclass.recentGamesId[i],
                    Score = mclass.summonerScoreText[i],
                    championPortraito = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/" + mclass.championName[0, i] + ".png"),
                    Item0 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 0] + ".png"),
                    Item1 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 1] + ".png"),
                    Item2 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 2] + ".png"),
                    Item3 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 3] + ".png"),
                    Item4 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 4] + ".png"),
                    Item5 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 5] + ".png"),
                    Item6 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 6] + ".png"),
                    listViewColor = winorlose

                });

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting the adapter again it's time the RecyclerView data is updated.